Filtering Croatian Plate Numbers on Oracle SQL
So, I have a list of plate numbers from different countries. If I want to filter Croatian plates, how can I do that? Croatian plate formats are like ZG 000-A, ZG 000-AA, ZG 0000-A or ZG 0000-AA. (Ignore the dashes)
I’ve tried several methods but can’t really filter the plates.
I have tried to filter according to first two letters that Croatia using and the plate lenght.

LIKE 'ZG %' maybe? What did you try?

How about a simple where with LIKE 'ZG %' ? I have not tried it but to be more precise how about  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('your db column', 'ZG [0]*-A+')

Yeah. Actually like you said I need something more precise. I need to write the format as a code and filter it but I don’t completely how.

Assuming that you want:

The start of the string (^)
Two letters ([A-Z]{2})
Followed by space ( )
Followed by three or four digits ([0-9]{3,4} or \d{3,4})
Followed by an optional dash (-?)
Followed by one or two letters ([A-Z]{1,2})
Followed by the end of the string ($).

Then you can use a regular expression:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(plate_number, '^[A-Z]{2} [0-9]{3,4}-?[A-Z]{1,2}$')

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (plate_number) AS
SELECT 'ZG 000-A'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZG 000-AA'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZG 0000-A'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZG 0000-AA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC00XY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01234' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



PLATE_NUMBER




ZG 000-A


ZG 000-AA


ZG 0000-A


ZG 0000-AA



fiddle

That regular expression you wrote seems awesome. I think I can use it for that regular expression to filter plate numbers in that format. Thank you very much. I will inform you about the output.

You can use the LIKE keyword in the WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern. Since each license plate starts with a ZG you can do:
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE foo LIKE 'ZG %'


The formats I wrote just examples. So the plates don’t have to start with ZG. They have to start with two lettter then following with 3 or 4 digits and then following with 1 or 2 letters.
